# How can display different panels using Request.queryString from one page to another?

Tags: c#, asp.net, response.redirect, request.querystring

I want to redirect "Manage-Cat-Subcat.aspx" from "Mainpage.aspx" to display panel1 and panel2 according to the selection by ddlCat and ddlSubCat(Dropdownlist)...

> Redirect to "Manage-Cat-Subcat.aspx" page to display **Panel1:**

```
protected void ddlcat_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlcat.SelectedItem.Text == "Other...")
    {
        Response.Redirect("ManageCat-SubCat.aspx?Register=pnlCat");
    }
}
```

> Redirect to "Manage-Cat-Subcat.aspx" page to display **Panel2:**

```
protected void ddlsubcat_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
    if (ddlsubcat.SelectedItem.Text == "Other...")
    {
        Response.Redirect("ManageCat-SubCat.aspx?Register=pnlSubCat");

    }

}
```

> This is what i did try in Manage-Cat_Subcat.aspx to display according to the value in 'Register'

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["Register"] = pnlCat)
    {
        Panel1.Visible = true;
    }
    else if (Request.QueryString["Register"] = pnlSubCat)
    {
        Panel2.Visible = true;
    }
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Main Page**

```
protected void ddlcat_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlcat.SelectedItem.Text == "Other...")
    {
        Response.Redirect("ManageCat-SubCat.aspx?Register=pnlCat");
    }
}

protected void ddlsubcat_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
    if (ddlsubcat.SelectedItem.Text == "Other...")
    {
        Response.Redirect("ManageCat-SubCat.aspx?Register=pnlSubCat");

    }

}
```

**Manage-Cat-Subcat.aspx**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
panel1.visible=false;
panel2.visible=false;
if(Request.QueryString["Register"]=="pnlCat")
{
panel1.visible=true;
}
if(Request.QueryString["Register"]=="pnlSubCat")
{
panel2.visible=true;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sasidharan Chandran!

Answer (score 0):

in your `ManageCat-SubCat.aspx` you can check value of `Request.QueryString["Register"]` and based on that value set the visibility of Panel2 and Panel1

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool visible = Request.QueryString["Register"] == "pnlCat";

    Panel1.Visible = visible;
    Panel2.Visible = !visible;
 }
```